# Google Cloud Logging: Search v1 Entries with V2 API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I'm currently writing logs to Cloud logging via google-fluentd which is great.  Now I want to filter and retrieve those entries.  The google-fluentd agent writes v1 format entries using the v1 API.

From what I gather the v1 API has no method to retrieve entries ( v1beta3.projects.logs.entries only exposes a 'write' method.  Is this true?

The v2 API exposes a list method for entries (v2beta1.entries.list), however it doesn't seem to be able to return v1 entries.

I'm in disbelief that it isn't possible to somehow retrieve v1 entries (the web console does it after all).  Can someone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I work for Google on Cloud Logging)

The v1 and v2 APIs store & retrieve the same underlying data, so you can read back entries using the v2 API that were written using the v1 API. Cloud Logging will automatically translate between the LogEntry representations.

You might be having trouble reading the entries back using the v2 API because some of the LogEntry fields are named differently, and the `filter` field in the `entries.list` request expects v2-style field names.

For example, to read back the most recent entry from the "syslog" log stream in the project ID "myproject" you could issue an API request like this:

```
POST https://logging.googleapis.com/v2beta1/entries:list
{
  "filter": "logName=projects/myproject/logs/syslog",
  "orderBy": "timestamp desc",
  "pageSize": 1,
  "projectIds": ["myproject"]
}
```

The `gcloud beta logging read` command in the Cloud SDK is also useful for experimenting with requests and seeing the structure of the entries being returned. You can pass the `--log-http` flag to have it show you the HTTP requests it's making, and `--format=json` to get the output in JSON instead of YAML.